# IPC over Socket - Messaging standards

Tags: .net, sockets, ipc

I am implementing IPC over sockets using .NET 2. I am wondering if there is an established best practice for messaging between the client and server (once the connection is established), or if this is defined on a case by case basis.

For instance, when passing a message from the client to the server, which of the following would be best:

- Custom defined messaging interface (sending a string of "STARTPROCESSX")
- Serializing objects to XML and communicating over those ( in this scenario, how would one call a method)

Some notes:

- Using WCF or IIS is not an option
- Once the connection is established the server needs to push data to the client without a request

If I have left any other potential messaging options out, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my solution, I ended up creating a custom defined messaging interface as it seemed more intuitive than others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at xml-rpc. It seems okay for what you want to do I guess